# Get first index in array where relation is true

Tags: python, numpy

How can I get the last index of the element in `a` where `b > a` when `a` and `b` have different length using numpy.

For instance, for the following values:

```
>>> a = np.asarray([10, 20, 30, 40])
>>> b = np.asarray([12, 25])
```

I would expect a result of `[0, 1]` (0.. because `12 > 10` -> index 0 in `a`; 1.. because `25 > 20` -> index 1 in `a`). Obviously, the length of the result vector should equal the length of `b` (and the values of the result list should be less than the length of `a` (as they refer to the indices in `a`)).

Another test is for `b = np.asarray([12, 25, 31, 9, 99])` (same `a` as above), the result should be `array([ 0,  1,  2, -1, 3])`.

Comment: Shouldn't the result be `[0, 0]` because `25 > 10`?

Comment: @Kasramvd: You're right. I didn't describe this properly. Let me rectify the question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A vectorized solution:

Remember that you can compare all elements in `b` with all elements in `a` using broadcasting:

```
b[:, None] > a
# array([[ True, False, False, False],     # b[0] > a[:]
#        [ True,  True, False, False]])    # b[1] > a[:]
```

And now find the index of the last `True` value in each row, which equals to the first `False` value in each row, minus 1

```
np.argmin((b[:, None] > a), axis=1) - 1
# array([0, 1])
```

Note that there might be an ambiguity as to what a returned value of `-1` means. It could mean

1. `b[x]` was **larger than all elements** in `a`, or
2. `b[x]` was **not larger than any element** in `a`

In our data, this means

```
a = np.asarray([10, 20, 30, 40])
b = np.asarray([9, 12, 25, 39, 40, 41, 50])

mask = b[:, None] > a
# array([[False, False, False, False],   # 9 is smaller than a[:], case 2
#        [ True, False, False, False],
#        [ True, False, False, False],
#        [ True,  True,  True, False],
#        [ True,  True,  True, False],
#        [ True,  True,  True,  True],   # 41 is larger than a[:], case 1
#        [ True,  True,  True,  True]])  # 50 is larger than a[:], case 1
```

So for case 1 we need to find rows with all `True` values:

```
is_max = np.all(mask, axis=1)
```

And for case 2 we need to find rows with all `False` values:

```
none_found = np.all(~mask, axis=1)
```

This means we can use the `is_max` to find and replace all case 1 `-1` values with a positive index

```
mask = b[:, None] > a
is_max = np.all(mask, axis=1)
# array([False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True])
idx = np.argmin(mask, axis=1) - 1
# array([-1,  0,  0,  2,  2, -1, -1])
idx[is_max] = len(a) - 1
# array([-1,  0,  0,  2,  2,  3,  3])
```

However be aware that **the index `-1` has a meaning**: Just like `3` it already means "the last element". So if you want to use `idx` for indexing, keeping `-1` as an invalid value marker may cause trouble down the line.

Comment: Awesome ;-)! Thanks.

Comment: Any idea how I can handle inputs (`b`) that are smaller than all values in `a`, i.e. for which there is no index? For `b = np.asarray([12, 25, 31, 9])` the result is `array([0, 1, 2, 3])` which is the same as if the last value in `b` (9) was > 40.

Comment: Your last edit provided what I need. The index is now `-1` which isn't ambiguous any more.

Comment: I just noticed that your solution now doesn't work for a case of element in `b > max(a)` (in which case a -1 will also be returned, but I need the last index of `a` instead...). So in the case of `b = np.asarray([12, 25, 31, 9, 99])`, the result should be `array([ 0,  1,  2, -1, 3])`, not `array([ 0,  1,  2, -1, -1])`.

Comment: the index `-1` is "the last index". Maybe you should mark too small elements differently

Comment: I have added some explanation what `-1` means, and a way of detecting what condition caused a `-1` to be returned.

Answer (score 0):

```
np.asarray([i for i in range(len(b)) if b[i]>a[i]])
```

This should give you the answer. Also the length does not have to be same as that of either a or b.

Answer (score 0):

Works even `a` has shorter length than `b` , first choose shorter list length then check if its has smaller numbers element wise :

```
[i for i in range(min(len(a),len(b))) if min(a, b, key=len)[i] > max(a, b, key=len)[i]]
# [0, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `zip` a and b to combine them and then `enumerate` to iterate it with its index

```
[i for i,(x,y) in enumerate(zip(a,b)) if y>x]
# [0, 1]
```